# How do I escape a string in a query?

Tags: 7, database

I received the following error using my module:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%m-%d') = 
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d') AND is_logout = 0' at line 1: SELECT id FROM 
ap_visits WHERE`current_ip` = '192.168.1.1' AND `url` = 
'http://www.mysite.com/php/4220/how-build-shopping-cart-w-checkout-php.html'' 
AND DATE_FORMAT(date_start, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d') AND 
is_logout = 0; Array ( ) in test_module_check() 
(line 164 of /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/sites/all/modules/test_module/test_module.module).
```

The error here is in the value of `url` column. It has an apostrophe at the end. So my question is on how can I escape this value so the apostrophe will not be an issue?

I am using `db_query`. This is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM ap_visits WHERE`current_ip` = '$current_ip' AND `url` = '$url' AND DATE_FORMAT(date_start, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d')  AND is_logout = 0";

$result = db_query($sql);
```

Comment: Hi. Did you tried with addslashes($url) ?

Comment: @Jaypabs While Stone Vo's answer is perfectely correct, you can't rely on it alone. You need to read up on basic [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Since you ask the question you ask, your site very likely has some serious security issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM {ap_visits}  WHERE current_ip = ':current_ip' AND url = ':url' AND DATE_FORMAT(date_start, '%%Y-%%m-%%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%%Y-%%m-%%d')  AND is_logout = 0";

$result = db_query($sql, array(':current_ip'=>$current_ip, ':url'=>$url));
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use the Database API, everything will be escaped properly

```
$query = db_select("ap_visits", "a")
    ->fields("a.id")
    ->condition("a.current_ip", $ip)
    ->condition("a.url", $url)
    ->where("DATE_FORMAT(a.date_start, '%%Y-%%m-%%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%%Y-%%m-%%d')")
    ->condition("a.is_logout", 0);
```

Output the query (for testing)

```
drupal_set_message($query->__toString());
drupal_set_message(print_r($query->arguments(),true));
```

Execute the query

```
$result = $query->execute();
```

Loop through the results

```
if ($result->rowCount())
{
    foreach ($result as $record)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
else
{
    // no data message
}
```

More here: https://drupal.org/developing/api/database